# problem in playing video uploaded in richtexteditor

Tags: javascript, asp.net, rich-text-editor

video is uploaded in rich-text-editor without any problem but when the content rendered in page, the below error has been occured in console.

- video extenstion is mp4

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal, reproducible code example so that we can help you. Do not comment or post an answer, but simply edit your post when you need to provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the information is not enough but the main reason that cause this issue is
the file you are uploading, in my opinion convert the file and do it again. you can use this site for free https://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4